# How to introduce the Composite Root in ASP.NET Web API Service

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2, restful-architecture

Want to design the Web API Service which exposes the Order Management API, Want to know , how to implement Composition Root pattern in ASP.NET Web API 2 service. Would be great if you provide reference to any sample source code.

Currently have come up with following libraries Core library , Service library and Data library. if we add the reference to all this libraries in Web API Service in order to make it a Composition Root, Is it a good practice. Need the guidance on this implementation.

Comment: You can add the dependencies/references directly or use [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx)...

Comment: @legends can you provide code sample or reference to the implementation.

Comment: fortunately, dotnet core fixes this with built-in dependency injection.  i know that doesn't help an older dotnet-framework application.  :(   #forFutureReaders       https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 2):

After searching a lot found very good explanation from Mark Seemann which answered this question. Please refer these links.

[Composition Root Reuse by Mark Seemann](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/06/composition-root-reuse/)

[Library Bundle Facade by Mark Seemann](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/21/library-bundle-facade/)

[Dependency Injection and Lifetime Management with ASP.NET Web API by Mark Seemann](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/09/28/DependencyInjectionandLifetimeManagementwithASP.NETWebAPI/)

Thanks Mark.

Comment: The "Dependency Injection and Lifetime Management with ASP.NET Web API by Mark Seemann" link was most helpful, IMHO.